# Mapview in UITableviewcell crashes in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, mkmapview

In my app I have a tableview of maps. When I scroll fastly or navigate the view controller the app crashes with segmentationFault 11. I created mapview in Nib.
Here is the code part in cellforRowAtIndexPath,

```
    MKCoordinateRegion region ={ {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  locationCoord=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(item.locationLatitude,item.locationLongitude);

     region.center=locationCoord;
     MKCoordinateSpan span;
     span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
     span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
     region.span=span;
     XMapAnnotation *annotation = [[XMapAnnotation alloc] init];
     annotation.coordinate = locationCoord;
     annotation.title=@"xyz";
     [cell.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
     [cell.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

In console am getting this error: -[VKTileKeyList containsKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x193c78b0.

In device log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf06a7c79
Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39462b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   VectorKit                       0x36b2edca -[VKTileProvider tileMatters:] + 74
2   VectorKit                       0x36b2ebfc -[VKTileProvider changeTileForKey:toState:withMetadata:withTile:forLayer:] + 88
3   VectorKit                       0x36b2eb98 -[VKTileProvider tileSource:didFetchTile:forKey:] + 56
4   VectorKit                       0x36b2eb50 -[VKTileSource fetchedTile:forKey:] + 40
5   VectorKit                       0x36b2fce4 -[VKTileSetBackedTileSource fetchedTile:forKey:] + 208
6   VectorKit                       0x36b2ead8 -[VKTileSource _fetchedTile:] + 220
7   VectorKit                       0x36b2e634 __49-[VKTileSource decodeData:downloadKey:sourceKey:]_block_invoke_3 + 104
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3994ad18 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3994ad04 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x39951788 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 264
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f11d814 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f11c0e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f086c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f086a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x33d7627e GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x3192a044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  xyz                         0x00016f04 main (main.m:16)
18  xyz                         0x0000bb7c start + 36
```

Comment: What's the error log?

Comment: post your actual exception